# Location of The Cloak of Stars brothel in Silverymoon

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, lore

Can anyone out there tell me where on the map of Silverymoon the location of [The Cloak of Stars brothel](http://dustin.wikidot.com/the-cloak-of-stars) run by the enchantress Felicia Morgenstern is? Other place descriptions tell you, if not the exact street, it'll say "on the Northbank" etc.

Answer (score 16):

## It’s someone else’s home-brewed location: put it anywhere you want

It has no official location. The Cloak of Stars is not from any official publication — it’s a location in [“Adventures of the Ebon League”](http://dustin.wikidot.com/dustin:campaign-outline), someone’s home campaign that they documented online. There exists no more information about  [The Cloak of Stars](http://dustin.wikidot.com/the-cloak-of-stars) than what is on that page. There is no map location decided for it.

If you want to borrow their location and NPC for your own home game that’s perfectly fine. However, you're on your own then, and if there are missing details you need then you’ll have to make them up yourself.